# MUI pickers + date-fns = TypeError: utils.getYearText is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js, date-fns

I am using [Material-UI V4](https://v4.mui.com/components/pickers/), [Material-UI Date/Time Pickers](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DateTimePicker) and [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) in a new project. My page is pretty simple and I am using the following [`DateTimePicker`](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DateTimePicker) component from Material UI:

```
            <DateTimePicker
              label="Date and time"
              inputVariant="outlined"
              value={searchDateTime}
              disablePast
              onChange={handleSearchDateTimeChange}
              showTodayButton
              fullWidth
              disabled={isScanning}
            />
```

Upon clicking the date picker, my app crashes with the following error:

> TypeError: utils.getYearText is not a function

How can I fix this?

Versions from `package.json`

```
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.11.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "date-fns": "^2.26.0",
    "next": "10.0.5",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Downgrade `@date-io/date-fns` from `2.11.0` to `1.3.13`.

From [the installation guide](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation) of Material UI Pickers:

> Important: For material-ui-pickers v3 use **v1.x** version of @date-io adapters.

Answer (score 3):

MUI: The AdapterDateFns class was moved from `@mui/lab` to `@mui/x-date-pickers`

You should use `import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns'`

More information about this migration on our blog: https://mui.com/blog/lab-date-pickers-to-mui-x/.

Comment: I was trying to import it like `import AdapterDayjs from '@mui/lab/AdapterDayjs'
` and it was not working, now using your import, just works